# Transition matrix proof

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes, induction

> Let $P=\begin{bmatrix}1-a&a\\b&1-b\end{bmatrix}$, with $0<a,b<1$. Show
>   that
>   $$P^n=\frac{1}{a+b}\begin{bmatrix}b&a\\b&a\end{bmatrix}+\frac{(1-a-b)^n}{a+b}\begin{bmatrix}a&-a\\-b&b\end{bmatrix}$$

I think it's possible to prove using induction principle, but I do not know if it's the best way

Let $n=1$
$$P^1=\frac{1}{a+b}\begin{bmatrix}b&a\\b&a\end{bmatrix}+\frac{(1-a-b)^1}{a+b}\begin{bmatrix}a&-a\\-b&b\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{a+b}\left(\begin{bmatrix}b&a\\b&a\end{bmatrix}+(1-a-b)^1\begin{bmatrix}a&-a\\-b&b\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}1-a&a\\b&1-b\end{bmatrix}$$

Assuming that is true for $n=k$
$$P^k=\frac{1}{a+b}\begin{bmatrix}b&a\\b&a\end{bmatrix}+\frac{(1-a-b)^k}{a+b}\begin{bmatrix}a&-a\\-b&b\end{bmatrix}$$

Now I need to show that is true for $n=k+1$
$$P^{k+1}=\frac{1}{a+b}\begin{bmatrix}b&a\\b&a\end{bmatrix}+\frac{(1-a-b)^{k+1}}{a+b}\begin{bmatrix}a&-a\\-b&b\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{a+b}\left(\begin{bmatrix}b&a\\b&a\end{bmatrix}+(1-a-b)^{k+1}\begin{bmatrix}a&-a\\-b&b\end{bmatrix}\right)=\frac{1}{a+b}\left(\begin{bmatrix}b&a\\b&a\end{bmatrix}+(1-a-b)^{k}(1-a-b)\begin{bmatrix}a&-a\\-b&b\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

but now I'm stuck

**EDIT:** Is there a way to finish it with induction?

Comment: Do you know anything about eigenvalues? This is not difficult, but slightly tedious, to prove by using diagonalization.

Comment: @Ian Yes, I know about eigenvalues

Comment: Try multiplying your (assumed) expression for $P^k$ by $P$ to get $P^{k+1}$. If it matches what you want $P^{k+1}$ to look like, then you're done!

Comment: That formula can't be correct. It's 'well known' that $\left(P^n\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ will converge to a matrix whose columns are all the Perron vector.

Comment: @GitGud This matrix is row-stochastic, not column-stochastic...

Comment: For a stochastic matrix (row-stochastic, column-stochastic, or both), one eigenvalue is 1. That means the other one is the trace minus one which is $1-a-b$. Find the eigenvectors, and write the diagonalization. Then simplify.

Comment: @Ian You're right. I didn't look at it straight. I've seen the other one so many times I just assumed it was it.

Comment: @Ian Is this a definition?It is that in the book that this exercise is, I saw no distinction on row-stochastic, column-stochastic. Anyway I will try to do what you said

Comment: To use induction successfully, you should multiply the formula for $P^k$ by $P$, rather than trying to factor $P$ out of the formula for $P^{k+1}$. Multiplication is easier than division.

Comment: @JohnSheridan Except in talking to people who have themselves used the opposite convention, the distinction is not that important. One can do everything in one convention and then straightforwardly translate everything into the other convention whenever necessary (by taking the transpose of all relevant vectors and matrices).

Comment: @JohnSheridan Note that actually both sides matter: if $f$ is a function on the state space written as a column vector, $q$ is a probability distribution on the state space written as a row vector, and $P$ is a row-stochastic matrix corresponding to the Markov chain $X_n$, then $q P f$ is the expected value of $f(X_1)$ given that $X_0$ is distributed according to $q$.

Comment: Matrix calculus is by far the simplest way here. Rewrite $P$ as $P=Q+(1-a-b)R$ where $(a+b)Q=\begin{bmatrix}b&a\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$ and $(a+b)R=\begin{bmatrix}a&-a\\-b&b\end{bmatrix}$, and note that $Q^2=Q$, $QR=RQ=0$ and $R^2=R$. Then the proof that $P^n=Q+(1-a-b)^nR$ for every $n$ is direct, either by induction or using the noncommutative version of the binomial theorem.